# How to malloc an array of string in ANSI C?

Tags: c++, c

In C++ I can allocate an array of strings (say 10 strings) very easily as:

```
string* arrayOfString = new string[10];
```

however I don't know how to do it in ANSI C. I tried:

```
char** arrayOfString = (*(char[1000])) malloc (sizeof (*(char[1000])));
```

But the compiler (MinGW 3.4.5) keeps saying that it is "Syntax error".
How to do it right?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If each string is of same size which is known at compile time, say it is 100, then you can do this<sup>1</sup>:

```
typedef char cstring[100]; //cstring is a new type which is 
                           //a char array of size 100

cstring *arrstring = malloc (1000 * sizeof (cstring));

int i;
for( i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; ++i)
     strcpy(arrstring[i], "some string of size less than or equal to 100");

for( i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; ++i)
     printf("%s\n", arrstring[i]);
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/oNA30

<sup>1. Note that as @Eregrith pointed out in the comment that cast is not advised if you compile your code as C. However, if you compile it as C++, then you need to write `(cstring*)malloc (1000 * sizeof (cstring))` but then in C++, you should avoid writing such code in the first place. A better alternative in C++ is, `std::vector<std::string>`  as explained at the bottom of this post.</sup>

If the size of each string is not known at compile time, or each string is not of same size, then you can do this:

```
char **arrstring =  malloc(sizeof(char*) * 1000); //1000 strings!
int i;
for(i = 0 ; i < 1000; ++i)
     arrstring[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * sizeOfString);
```

I'm assuming same size `sizeOfString` for all 1000 strings. If they're different size, then you've to pass different value in each iteration, something like this:

```
for(i = 0 ; i < 1000; ++i)
     arrstring[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * sizeOfEachString[i]);
```

I hope that helps you, and I also hope you can do the rest yourself.

---

By the way, in C++, you should not do this:

```
string* arrayOfString = new string[10]; //avoid new as much as possible!
```

Instead, you should do this:

```
std::vector<std::string>  strings;
strings.reserve(10);
```

Comment: Casting the return of malloc is not advised (as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1151654) explained) but is necesseray if you plan to compile your code as C++.

Comment: @Eregrith: Oh.. I didn't know that which is purely C thing and I don't know C-thing much. Thanks for the comment. I edited my post.

Comment: typedef'ing an array? really?

Comment: +1 for "avoid new as much as possible!".

I can usually tell how long a person has been programming C++ by how many different places memory allocations occur in their code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one to allocate 100 strings. Each string is at most 1000 characters long.

```
char** arrayOfString = (char**) malloc (sizeof(char[100][1000]));
```

Comment: Yes. Why is C so hard for people to understand in the "C" section of stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

```
#define N  10   // Number of strings
#define M  20   // Size of the strings

/* Please check malloc return value is not NULL */

char **arrayOfString = malloc(sizeof *arrayOfString * N);

for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    arrayOfString[i] = malloc(M);
}
```

Comment: it should be for (i = 0; i < N; i++), shouldn't it?

Comment: I think you mean `i < N` in the `for`?

Comment: How and with what are you compiling this? I'm getting these errors with gcc bundling this up in a .cpp file including only stdio.h and stdlib.h. temp.cpp:9: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char**’
temp.cpp:11: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘for’
temp.cpp:11: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘<’ token
temp.cpp:11: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘++’ token
cnorton@steamboy:~/projects/clojure/repl-test$

Comment: @octopusgrabbus Your filename ending with .cpp extension, asking to compile it with gcc, gcc will use the C++ language to compile it. Use `-xc` option to gcc to compile it as a C program or rename the   filename extension to .c.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus I roll back your changes. I'm not sure they add something while they change the code style. Why not `void` as a function parameter?  Why include stdio.h? Why { now in a new line? Why  ** not bound to the function identifier?

Comment: @ouah I could not get your sample to compile. I did not use void, because the function needed to return the head of the array of strings.